# Can Jedi communicate with each other across the galaxy through the Force without alerting the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I recently got around to starting *Star Wars Rebels*. In the episode "Path of the Jedi" (season 1 episode 10) Ezra and Kanan are inside a Jedi temple. The voice of

> Master Yoda

provides guidance to both Kanan and Ezra. Wouldn't communicating with another Jedi across the galaxy be something that would leave a powerful disturbance in the Force? How did this go unnoticed by Vader, The Emperor, and the Inquisitors?

Assuming that it is somehow possible to do this without bringing the empire down on their head, why wouldn't they use this to communicate with other surviving Jedi? Even if it somehow required being in or near a Jedi Temple, we know of at least one case (Cal in Jedi Fallen Order) where a conversation with

> Yoda

would have been helpful while in a former temple.

**Was this ever expanded upon in later episodes or in other media?**

Answer (score 5):

There's no indication in canon media that telepathic communication via the Force can be detected by anyone else without the sender's intent. In the cases that we see in the films (such as Luke calling out to Leia), Vader shows no signs of noticing, despite being nearby. It's only the visual form of communication used in the sequels that seems to be noticeable to others, and even then it seems to work by sight only, not by disturbances in the Force.

As to why this wasn't used at other times, it's possible that it was—Yoda and Obi-Wan could have talked to each other while in exile, and Yoda even says that he's "watched" Luke for a long time, despite being on Dagobah.

In Cal's case, there are a number of reasons why Yoda might not have reached out: he might not have realized Cal was alive; he might not have known Cal was at the temple; he might not have had any useful advice for Cal's situation; the Force energies at the temple might have behaved differently than at the other temple; etc.

Comment: They might need a Force VPN though

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the various legends and canon sources, it is a mater of having a noticeable "signature". Especially compared to the "background".

Palpatine was able to escape the Jedi Council, in part because they had build their temple on a Dark Side shrine and he was really good at lowering his signature.

Yoda escape the purge, because of the Dark Side cave on Dagobah.

The Temple itself had a presence in the force. So against that signature, Yodas communicaiton would have been realy hard to notice. Especially if he used the Temples force as a "booster", so he could expend extra little energy.

If Vader or the Emperor were there? They propably would have noticed. And might even be able to track him back. But that is before even

> the inquisitors enter the picture.

Comment: don't forget that the temple is on Lothal, which is Ezra's home planet, so that may give it an extra buff